# Search a number with for loop and different criteria

Tags: java

I am new in this whole coding stuff and I have no idea what I do wrong?

My task is to write a for loop to search a number(x), with the criteria:

- It is a number from 1 to 100
- If you divide x with 6 the remainder is 0
- If you divide x with 7 the remainder is 0
- You can divide x with 4
- The cross sum is 6

```java
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    for(int x = 1;
            (x%6 == 0) &&
            (x%7 == 0) &&
            (x/4) &&
            (6= (x%10) + (x/10));
                    x++) {
        System.out.println("Die gesuchte Zahl ist: " +x);
    }

  }
}
```

My editor show me that there is a unexpected type in this line: `(6= (x%10) + (x/10));`
and this error "bad operand types for binary operator '&&'" in this line: `(x%7 == 0) &&`

Comment: Java doesn't let you assign values to literal numbers like 6.  Did you mean `(6 == ...`?

Comment: What does "you can divide x with 4" mean? 5 can be divided by 4, the result is 1.25. Or does it mean something else? The statements before contain "the remainder is 0", but this statement does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one number **i.e 42** which satisfies all conditions.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i % 6 == 0 && i % 7 == 0 && (i/10) + (i%10) == 6)
        System.out.println("The number is : " + i);
}
```

Comment: I upvoted the answer but you forgot a criterion: 42 cannot be divided by 4. No number satisfies all conditions unless the criterion "can be divided by 4" means something different.

Comment: Yes. No number will satisfy with the combination of *You can divide x with 4* criteria.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop does not work like that.

What you're trying to do is check all numbers from 1 to 100 and stop searching when you find one that matches all criteria.

There are several ways to do that, but I would pick this: Use a `for` loop to cycle over all numbers from 1 to 100. Check if all the conditions apply, and if they do, print out the number and leave the loop.

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
  if ((x % 6 == 0) && 
      (x % 7 == 0) && 
      (x % 4 == 0) && 
      ((x / 10) + (x % 10) == 6)) {
    System.out.println("BINGO: " + x);
    break;
  }
}
```

For some reason you treated the condition with the 4 as different from the others, but it is not (*can be divided by* = the remainder is zero).

If you wanted to combine the if within the for, you can do it, but it works the other way round: you are supposed to put the condition required *to proceed* to the next run of the loop. It becomes this:

```
int x;
for (x = 1; 
    (x <= 100) &&
    (x % 6 == 0) && 
    (x % 7 == 0) && 
    (x % 4 == 0) && 
    ((x / 10) + (x % 10) == 6);
    x++) {
  // Does nothing here
}
System.out.println("BINGO: " + x);
```

Notice that you need to declare `x` as an integer outside the `for` loop because you want to read it after you `break` out of the cycle.

The first version is definitely more readable (to humans).

Comment: First of all thank you, it helped me a lot, but the problem of your code is that you define the rest of x/4 and that was not want the task want. there should be only a rest and its not defined if it is 0 or 1 or 2... But you explaiened it very good.

Comment: You're welcome! But I don't understand what you mean with «There should be a rest» if this remainder can be any number including 0. Any number can be divided by 4 by this definition…